# Regex replacement: strings to function call

Tags: php, regex, string, replace, autoit

My AutoIt script has lots of strings. For example :

```
;This is AutoIt
$string1 = "This is a test string" & @crlf & "Wow, autoit syntax!"
$string2 = "This string has a var. Var1=" & $var1
$wow = random_function("Another string") & "this is getting complex"
magic_function("var1=" & $var1 & @crlf & "other var=" & $var2)
$multivar = "This string has 2 vars: var1=" & $var1 & " var2=" $var2"
```

I want to replace every string with a function call. So the above script would become:

```
;This is AutoIt
$string1 = get_string(1) & @crlf & get_string(2)
$string2 = get_string(3,$var1)
$wow = random_function(get_string(4)) & get_string(5)
magic_function(get_string(6,$var1) & @crlf & get_string(7,$var2))
$multivar = get_string(8,$var1,$var2)
```

OR

```
;This is AutoIt
$string1 = get_string(1,@crlf)
$string2 = get_string(3,$var1)
$wow = random_function(get_string(4)) & get_string(5)
magic_function(get_string(6,$var1,@crlf,$var2))
$multivar = get_string(8,$var1,$var2)
```

Both are good to me. I am looking for a regex solution. Scripts contain strings that shouldn't be replaced, but let me do that part. I just need the regex part.

My take using PHP:

```
//This is php
$file = "test.au3"
$lines = file($file)
foreach($lines as $index => $line){
    $newLine = preg_replace(/*magic regex here*/);
}
```

Replacement can be done to every single line (I don't have multi line strings).

Answer (score 0):

That cannot be done with regex alone.  However, it can be done using regex + stateful parsing.

Based on the possible syntax cases in your example, I've put together a script that does the job.  I wrote it in Python since I'm more comfortable with that language than PHP, but the code + comments should be clear enough for someone to convert it to PHP if Python is not available to you for this task.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import fileinput
import re

# Values you might want to modify
filename = "test.au3"
replacementFunctionName = "get_string"
replacementForConcatenator = ","



# Regexes to identify raw AutoIt elements
string = r"""(?:"(?:[^"]|"(?="))*"|'(?:[^']|'(?='))*')"""  # triple quotes is just Python
macro = r"@\w+"  # the prefix r makes the \ a literal (in the string, not the regex)
variable = r"\$\w+"
concatenator = r"\s*&\s*"

# Regexes to identify compound AutoIt elements
nonConcatenator = "(?:" + string + "|" + macro + "|" + variable + ")"
capturingNonConcatenator = "(" + string + "|" + macro + "|" + variable + ")"
zeroOrMoreConcatenatedNonConcatenators = "(?:" + concatenator + nonConcatenator + ")" + "*"

# The combined search regex and its compiled form
search = string + zeroOrMoreConcatenatedNonConcatenators
searchRe = re.compile(search)  # compiling lets us specify a start index for searches



# Process file in place
count = 0  # used to correctly number AutoIt string literal instances
for line in fileinput.input(filename, inplace=True):
    newLine = ""

    # Convert old line to new line
    indexInLine = 0
    matchOfSearchRe = searchRe.search(line, indexInLine)
    while matchOfSearchRe is not None:
        matchReplacement = ""

        # Replace each AutoIt string in matched substring with number
        # and replace each concatenator with a comma
        elementsOfMatch = re.split(capturingNonConcatenator, matchOfSearchRe.group(0))
        for elem in elementsOfMatch:
            if re.match(string, elem):
                count += 1
                matchReplacement += str(count)
            elif re.match(concatenator, elem):
                matchReplacement += replacementForConcatenator
            else:
                matchReplacement += elem

        # Place modified contents of match in a replacement function call
        matchReplacement = replacementFunctionName + "(" + matchReplacement + ")"

        # Append most recently skipped region before match and replacement for match
        newLine += line[indexInLine:matchOfSearchRe.start()]
        newLine += matchReplacement

        # Update loop control variables
        indexInLine = matchOfSearchRe.end()
        matchOfSearchRe = searchRe.search(line, indexInLine)

    # Append rest of line after final match
    newLine += line[indexInLine:]

    # Replace old line in filename with new line in place
    print(newLine.rstrip())
```

On a cursory test, this script converted

```
;This is autoit
$string1 = "This is a test string" & @crlf & "Wow, autoit syntax!"
$string2 = "This string has a var. Var1=" & $var1
$wow = random_function("Another string") & "this is getting complex"
magic_function("var1=" & $var1 & @crlf & "other var=" & $var2)
$multivar = "This string has 2 vars: var1=" & $var1 & " var2=" & $var2
```

to

```
;This is autoit
$string1 = get_string(1,@crlf,2)
$string2 = get_string(3,$var1)
$wow = random_function(get_string(4)) & get_string(5)
magic_function(get_string(6,$var1,@crlf,7,$var2))
$multivar = get_string(8,$var1,9,$var2)
```

If the possible syntax cases are more varied than what is in your example, then this script is not guaranteed to work.  However, it can be modified to suit your needs simply by adding to or changing the "regexes to identify raw AutoIt elements" and the associated "regexes to identify compound AutoIt elements."  Any modifications will be collected in the `search` variable so that nothing else should need to be changed in the main body of the script.

Note that I modified your example input in my test case.  It appears that your example had two syntax errors on the last line:  a missing `&` and an extra `"`.